# "thread blocked indefinitely in an STM transaction" in a case where threads are never blocked

Tags: multithreading, haskell, asynchronous, race-condition, stm

I'm using the `async` library in conjunction with `stm` in my program.

The main thread forks two threads which run until one of them (it could be either one) encounters a solution. The solution is returned via a TMVar. Neither of them ever waits on any `TMVar` except to call `putTMVar` when the solution is found and one of them is guaranteed to run forever unless killed. So how could I possibly be getting "thread blocked indefinitely in an STM transaction" (which seems to happen approximately one in every twenty times) given that at least one of the child threads doesn't execute any blocking STM transactions (or die) until storing a result.

Note the two child threads communicate somewhat with *each other* using `TVar`s, but not with `TMVar`s.

Simplified code:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  output <- newEmptyTMVar
  result <- withAsync (child1 output) $ \_ -> withAsync (child2 output) $ \_ ->
    let go = do
          result <- atomically $ takeTMVar output
          if someCondition result
            then return result
            else go
    in  go
  print result

child1 :: TMVar Result -> IO ()
child1 output = go 0
  where
    go i = do
      case computation1 i of
        Nothing -> return ()
        Just x -> atomically $ putTMVar x
      go (i + 1)

child2 :: TMVar Result -> IO ()
-- Does some other stuff, but also only interacts with its argument to
-- give back a result, same as child1.
```

Comment: Why do you think this isn't possible?  Consider the sequence of operations: `child1` writes to the TMVar, `main` takes from the TMVar, `child1` writes to the TMVar (it is once again full), `child1` and `child2` block in an STM transaction trying to `putTMVar` and `main` has no live reference to `output` by this point.  Both child threads and thus blocked in an STM transaction.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson I think the OP expects that `withAsync` will eventually kill (cancels) those threads, so there is no real deadlock here. However, the RTS does not keep "thread kills" into account, and triggers an arguably spurious "deadlock" exception. I'm not arguing the RTS is wrong in its detection strategy, but here it copes with asyncs.

Comment: I've run into similar issues in the past, and this is indeed expected RTS behavior. Relevant links: https://github.com/simonmar/async/issues/14 https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/9401 https://github.com/simonmar/async/pull/15

Comment: @chi Makes sense.  It just seems that this is a race even in the best case.  What wins between the killing of the child threads or the RTS recognizing there is no reader of `output` and throwing the exception for all blocked children.  This is particularly realistic if there is more than `takeTMVar` in that branch of `main`.

Comment: What's the right way to do this?

Comment: (I edited the code so that the main thread is deciding whether or not to accept each solution either of the children produce)